# VMWare extend existing VM disk size using python

Tags: python, api, vmware

I have looked into the Vsphere python SDK https://github.com/vmware/vsphere-automation-sdk-python for finding sample to extend an existing VM disk in vCenter. There seems to be no way to modify existing disk, we can only remove an existing disk and add a new disk.

So is there anyway we can perform this using python ? Any samples is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually used the SOAP API provide by pyvmomi to extend the disk.

```
def extend_disk(client, vm, size, disk_number):
    disk_label = 'Hard disk '+disk_number
    disk_size = int(size) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
    disk = None
    for device in vm.config.hardware.device:
        if hasattr(device.backing, 'fileName'):
            if device.deviceInfo.label == disk_label:
                disk = device
                break
    if disk:
        if disk.capacityInBytes >= disk_size:
            return 1
        else:
            disk.capacityInBytes = disk_size
            updated_spec = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec(device=disk, operation="edit")
            spec = vim.vm.ConfigSpec()
            spec.deviceChange.append(updated_spec)
            WaitForTask(vm.Reconfigure(spec))
            return 0
    else:
        return 1
```